# What techniques are useful to get a ChatGPT application to reveal information about a prompt which attempts to obscure itself?

Tags: chatgpt

For example, say I am interacting with a prompt-based application that is built upon ChatGPT, and the application's prompt has taken measures such as those described in the question [How can I encourage ChatGPT to not reveal specific context, such as a fixed prompt that I want to keep hidden?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/39/33). How can I prompt the application by adding new context to reveal information from/about that hidden context containing the application's prompt?

Note: I recognize that this question is inherently broad, since I haven't specified a specific "hidden prompt". But I think doing so would take away from the usefulness of the question, and I think that such generalized techniques do exist, since I know that people can and have "reverse-engineered" prompts without knowing what those prompts were.

Answer (score 1):

That's called ***"prompt leaking"*** and it's basically tricking the LLM into giving you the base *`'system'`* prompt. I referenced this same article in this question about [Prompt Injection](https://medium.com/google-cloud/generative-ai-protect-your-llm-against-prompt-injection-in-production-f99852910a8e)

Here is my [previous answer that references "jailbreaking"](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/102/what-constitutes-jailbreaking-genai/118#118) which isn't really a proper term given there is no sandboxed hardware to "break into" here.