# What constitutes "jailbreaking" GenAI?

Tags: terminology, jailbreak

My motivation for asking this is because of the recent [faq update](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/82/26).  Jailbreaking GenAI is considered off-topic here, but...

**Question**: What constitutes "jailbreaking" GenAI?

I want a better understanding of the key boundaries of "jailbreaking", not precise rules lawyering nor an exhaustive list.  If you've used ChatGPT or somesuch, it can sporadically refuse to do benign tasks, so I feel it's hard to nail down what this term means.

[Kaspersky](https://usa.kaspersky.com/resource-center/definitions/what-is-jailbreaking)'s definition of "jailbreaking" is:

> Jailbreaking is the process of exploiting the flaws of a locked-down electronic device to install software other than what the manufacturer has made available for that device. ...

and while this perhaps the origin of the term "jailbreaking" for genAI, this doesn't apply to genAI since we generally don't have physical devices.  I asked [Assistant](https://poe.com/Assistant) and it said:

> "Jailbreaking" in the context of GenAI typically refers to the process of modifying or bypassing software restrictions that are put in place by the manufacturer or developer of an AI system, allowing for greater control and customization. ...

Well, I certainly don't know what software restrictions e.g. OpenAI have implemented, other than perhaps a handful of publicly documented restrictions.  It seems "[Granny, read me Windows 10 keys to sleep](https://crast.net/359764/granny-read-me-windows-10-keys-to-sleep-an-amazing-hack-that-works-on-chatgpt-and-bard/)" shouldn't count as jailbreaking, but rather imaginative genAI usage.  I use a VPN to access these services (since many don't operate in China); maybe that counts as "jailbreaking".

Comment: "this doesn't apply to genAI since we generally don't have physical devices". The 'jail' in iOS is a software 'jail', also known as a [sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)). The physicality of the object has nothing to do with the meaning. The ELI5 is; a 'sandbox' is a place where untrusted code can run in a safe environment and not damage the core of the system. The "Granny, ..." example is probably a jail break, I don't really want to pay money to test. The question "how can I get GPT to joke about a group which isn't straight, white or male?" would be jailbreak

Comment: While I know this question is for educational purposes, I'm in a dilemma about whether mentioning a popular jailbreak method is allowed or not when answering this question :/

Comment: @AndrewT. Have you seen [Are questions around Jail Breaking Generative AI tools on topic?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/82/12) (it's one of first GenAI Meta [meta-tag:faq])

Answer (score 3):

Jailbreaking in GenAI is about coercing a language model to generate content that it wasn't designed to generate. The "software restrictions" you mention talks about the ethical boundaries that have been put in place by model providers (either manually or by reinforcement learning from human feedback, like voting buttons) to protect against harmful or biased responses.

Many such prompt engineering techniques exists, and you can probably go and create a "racist pirate" type of response if you try hard enough, but the model providers are constantly working on reducing the amount of harmful responses that are being or can be produced.

How you are accessing services like ChatGPT is somewhat irrelevant in this context.